# Why I get \r\r\n as newline instead of \r\n as newline char in Windows

Tags: java, readfile

I have below readfile() java function to read .htm files

```
private String readfile(String inputDoc) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    String text = null;
    //open input stream to file
    fis = new FileInputStream(inputDoc);
    isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    int c;
    while( (c = isr.read()) != -1 ) {
        buffer.append((char)c);
    }
    text = buffer.toString();
    isr.close();
    return text;
}
```

Here is example snippet of input doc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><html>

<head>
```

For some reason text string returned from readfile() is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><html>\r\r\n<head>`

**but I expect it to be** `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><html>\r\n<head>`

as it is outlined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) newline char in windows \r\n

I ran above function in IntelliJ Idea on Windows 7. (IDEA default encoding is set to UTF-8)

Does anyone know why I get this weird result from readfile(String inputDoc) function for newline

Comment: Are you sure the original file does not have `\r\\r\n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this because it is like this in the input file. Try to open the input file in a hex editor to verify.

Comment: +1,  Thanks! I opened the input file in a Hex editor I get this:
<html>0D 0D 0A<head>. I assume that proves it is in input file? Can you speculate, how it entered in input file in first place. I thought in any case newline will always be \r\n not \r\r\n.

Answer (score 7):

When you write the `\n`, it is expanded to `\r\n` on Windows for portability.  That way, no matter what operating system you run it on, you get the correct result with no additional code: `\r\n` on Windows, or just `\n` on Unix.  It looks like you are reading the input in binary mode (In text mode, the same expansions happen in reverse: any `\r\n` in the input becomes just `\n`, so you again do not have to worry about OS), so you see the `\r`.  Then, when you write the `\n`, it gets expanded to `\r\n`, leaving two `\r`s.