# Line endings in child_process.exec() stdout

Tags: node.js, wmic, line-endings

I'm building my custom wrapper around wmic using node.js and I have problems parsing it's output. Not a problem, but I just don't know why this happens.

I thought line endings are either `\r` or `\r\n` and decided to look on it
Here's a demo piece of code:

```
exec('wmic process', {maxBuffer :1000*1024}, function (err, stdout, stderr){
    let location =stdout.indexOf('\n')-6;
    let region =stdout.substr(location, 10);
    console.log(region);

    let buf = new Buffer(stdout);
    let buf2 = new Buffer(30);
    buf.copy(buf2, 0, location, location+30);
    console.log(buf2);
});
```

I looked at `region` and saw this:

[image]

For some reason there are two `\r`s instead of one!

Output of `console.log(buf2)` also shows this:

```
<Buffer 6f 75 6e 74 20 20 0d 0d 0a 53 79 73 ...
                          ^^ ^^ ^^
```

I was ready to split lines by `\r\r\n` when I decided to pipe its output to text file and look through a hex editor:

```
wmic process > wmic.txt
```

[image]

What? Where are two `\r`s?

I have two questions:

1. Where does Node get second `\r` from? I tried to find some info, but Google is kind of heavy on queries such as `\r\r\n`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059212/why-i-get-r-r-n-as-newline-instead-of-r-n-as-newline-char-in-windows) is the closest I could get, I'm not sure if it's related
2. Why hex editor shows 16bit encoding and Node doesn't? I suppose I should've specified encoding in `exec()` options but I don't know which one. `chcp` shows 437th codepage, but I kind of want it to work in other codepages as well.

Comment: Are you sure the characters are coming from Node and not from your input?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you... I don't input anything...

Comment: You're executing `wmic process` and reading its output. That's your input. Are you sure the characters aren't there?

Comment: You mean `stdin` kind of input? No, these above are only lines of code besides `let exec = require('child_process').exec;`